# Jquery conflict problems with other scripts

Tags: jquery

Hello on my website i am runnig many Jquery plugins like, carouFredSel, nivoslider, cloud-zom etc... they work fine, until i added this jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lightbox_me.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
        function launch() {
             $('#sign_up').lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() { $('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus()}});
        }
        $('#try-1').click(function(e) {
            $("#sign_up").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
                $("#sign_up").find("input:first").focus();
            }});
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');

            $(".sign_up2").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
                $(".sign_up2").find("input:first").focus();
            }});
            e.preventDefault();

    });
</script>
```

after adding this code, my slider stoped working and also image zoom... HO TO MAKE NON-CONFLICT?

Comment: [jQuery noConflict method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Can you please provide the error from your JS console that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you have an orphaned `e.preventDefault();` in your code.  Clean that up first. Then we'll see if you are still having a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Either use jquery noconflict

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Or limit the scope of your calls to jquery using

```
(function($) {
    // code here
})(jquery)
```

Comment: I already tried the nonConflict method, with no success, maybe i did it wrong.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(function() {
            function launch() {
                 j('#sign_up').lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() { j('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus()}});
            }
            j('#try-1').click(function(e) {
                j("#sign_up").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
     j("#sign_up").find("input:first").focus();
    }});
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            j('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');

Comment: This looks okay but you should wrap it in a .ready() clause and pass j in as a parameter